# Are cats fine around turtles?

Tags: turtles

I'm considering adopting a cat which is friendly and likes to play.
Will this cat attack  or injure my three turtles?

I have three of them,
Two Attack anything in sight, the other is extra shy.

Should I take any precautions? If so, like what?

Answer (score 3):

Each cat varies but rule of thumb is to never let predatory species interact with prey species unsupervised (if at all). Turtles will at least have some defense but they should be kept separate.

There are many horror stories out there of peoples cats or dogs getting along fine with their pocket pets (ex. rabbits or birds) for years then one day instincts kick in and they come home to deceased pets.

Comment: You seem to assume here that turtles are prey. Wrong, very wrong. ;-)

Comment: No at all ;) unless they're snappers but small sliders or painted turtles for example would be considered prey. One of the many reasons we tell people to keep their cats indoors is because they kill our wildlife - we have a turtle species in my province going extinct from out kitties killing them in large numbers.